# What decides the turn order in Bravely Default?

Tags: bravely-default

I am fighting a boss, and, usually, the turn order goes like this:

```
Ringabel -> Edea -> Boss -> Agnes -> Tiz
```

I am guessing that this is all decided by the `AGI` stat, which makes sense.

However, sometimes, this is simply not the order. Sometimes the boss goes first. Other times, Edea or Agnes go first.

What else can affect the turn order? No - *what* decides the turn order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, **Agility is the defining stat that determines turn order**. That being said, there is some randomness that can occur occasionally. However if your speed is ~20 above the bosses, you will take the first turn. That being said, there are occasions where a character with 44 speed (AGL) will play before a character with 48 speed

Using the left analog stick during battle and pressing the 'A' button will show the character stats of each character, including the speed or Agility.